# jquery sticky sidebar responsive

Tags: jquery, sticky

I have this jquery code which works great:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.stickysidebarscroll("#top-left",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
});
    </script>

        <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
  $.stickysidebarscroll("#top-right",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
});
```

But I want to disable the jquery action when the screen size is >991px.

Any one know what I should add to the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the width of the viewport...

This runs your script when the viewport width is less than 991px:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $( window ).width() < 991 ){
        $.stickysidebarscroll("#top-right",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By screen size you mean width/height? Assuming its width, a simple if statement would do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 991 ){
            $.stickysidebarscroll("#top-right",{offset: {top: 10, bottom: 200}});
        }
    });
```

Comment: What I want is to disable  $.stickysidebarscroll when the viewport width is less than 991px so that the sticky columns doesn't work and the columns stack up nicely one below the other.